# How to link AWS Lambda events for retries of a given invocation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Does the `requestId` (in `requestContext`) change on retries? If so, what can I use to know which event is a retry of which previous failed event without adding a custom ID item in the payload? With AWS Batch the equivalent thing is easy because on retries one has the same `jobId`, but not sure what the equivalent is in Lambda.

Comment: The only `requestContext` I can think of is `event.requestContext`, which comes in from an API Gateway Lambda proxy integration invocation.  That data would be provided by APi Gateway, but those Lambda invocations are always synchronous (so there are no retries; a non-proxy Lambda integration could be asynchronous but IIRC wouldn't automatically provide `requestContext`.).  Perhaps you're thinking of `context.awsRequestId`?  You may need to describe the environment more fully.

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-aws-lambda-destinations/ shows the event format when sending to a lambda destination; the example JSON is halfway down the page.

Comment: Ah, I wasn't thinking about *Destinations* at all, and I thought you were referring to the contents of `event` during the invocation, rather than the destination payload. An async invocation in your context only "fails" when all retries are exhausted, not with each fail-before-retry, so you would not see multiple notifications on retry.  *"When a function invocation fails, such as when retries are exhausted or the event age has been exceeded (hitting its TTL), Destinations routes the record to the destination resource for every failed invocation for further investigation or processing."*